# How do I put clips into a Group in Clip View?

Tags: ableton-live

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKqhi.png

It seems like Dragging and Dropping them doesn't work or isn't expected by the Ableton Live 10 trial.

Comment: You still have your previous question open. You don't put clips into groups, you put tracks into groups. Have you found the manual?